# Can I use ON DUPLICATE KEY update with an INDEX?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table structure that has a primary key and then a compound index based on two columns called user_idx_name.  If I use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE does it look at the **PRIMARY** key, **user_idx_name** key or both?

My table structure looks like this:

```
Keyname         Type    Unique    Packed    Column    Cardinality    Collation  Null  Comment
PRIMARY         BTREE    Yes        No        id        67420          A        
user_idx_name   BTREE    Yes        No        user_id   67420          A        
                                              file_name 67420          A 


INSERT INTO table1
(`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`)
VALUES
('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`col2`='val2',
`col3`='val3', [...]
```

Do I need to specifiy my INDEX KEY called user_idx_name ?

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY` looks at `UNIQUE` keys only.  `PRIMARY` is a type of `UNIQUE` key, so it will be checked, as well as all other `UNIQUE` keys,

Comment: mysql will look at ALL unique keys in the table (including the primary key). If the insert causes a duplicate key violation on **ANY** of the keys, the insert will be turned into an update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a **UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY**, MySQL performs an UPDATE of the old row.